# how do i use subdomain in rails to redirect users to thier domains

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to use a subdomain to redirect users to their subdomain

example

```
https://usersubdomain.mydomain.com
```

My setup is as fellow,

Each user has an account which is created when a new user is registered

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
.........
     has_one :account
      after_initialize :set_account

         def set_account
           build_account unless account.present?
         end
 ......        
end
```

The account has subdomain attributes which I intend to use as the Url for the user

```
create_table "accounts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "subdomain"
    t.bigint "user_id"
    ..........
```

On user creation, I used nested attributes to create the subdomain for the account. I am using devise

User Registration.

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= render "devise/shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>

  <%= f.fields_for :account do |a| %>
    <div class="field">
    <%= a.label :subdomain %><br />
    <%= a.text_field :subdomain%>
     ..........
```

Resources are scoped through account

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_action :set_account

    def require_account!
        redirect_to home_index_url(subdomain: nil) if @account.nil?
    end
    def set_account
      @account = Account.find_by(subdomain: request.subdomain)
    end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :posts
  root to: 'posts#index'

  get 'home/index'
end
```

With this setup. I need to manually enter the subdomain to get the page of the user. If not I am always redirected to the home index page as intended.

I use lvh.me on the localhost. So must enter `subdomain.lvh.me:3000` on the address bar to get the user page. So how can the subdomain be added automatically when users sign in Thanks

All The controllers are scoped with

```
@resource = @accout.resoures
```

I am trying to build a multitenant app

Answer (score 0):

I get the impression that since you know how to get the subdomain from the request and from the database what you are having problem is building the URL to where you want to send the user from the on right? if that is the case you might be looking for url_for handling the this in detail https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.2/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor.html

for example

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.url_for(controller: "admin/users", action: 'show', id: 1, host: 'somehost.org', port: '8080', subdomain: "yadah")
=> "http://yadah.somehost.org:8080/admin/users/1"
```

but also you can do `users_url(subdomain: user.subdomain)`.

Dont forget you can use regular expression in you constraints too

```
 constraints: {subdomain: /.+/}
```

or a lambda

```
constraints: lambda { |r| r.subdomain.present? && r.subdomain != 'www' }
```

user this with devise's after sign in path

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protected
    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      request.env['omniauth.origin'] || stored_location_for(resource) || root_path
    end
end
```

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in

Comment: Where does the above code go? I understand how to redirect users after sign in with devise but I don't understand how to append their subdomain to the URL

Comment: @foliwe83 I pasted the example from the devise documentation, the URL you want to redirect is built by doing users_url(subdomain: user.subdomain), does it make sense now?